# Pipe() System Call

Tags: c, bash, shell, pipe, system-calls

I am learning about piping and shell in a Systems class. I'm messing around with `strace`. I am running it on some program called `dpipe`.

In the `strace` log, I see the following:

```
pipe([3, 4])
pipe([5, 6])
```

What do those integers represent? I under that piping is basically used in shell to route the output of one command, to the input of another using `|`. So it just makes our lives easier. In this case, what do the array of numbers up there represent? Furthermore, if `piping` is just used in shell, why is there C syscall for it? Is that made solely for those who want to write their own shell (to make their lives easier)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignacio explained correctly that the numbers in square brackets are the two file descriptors returned by the [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) system call.  The first is the read end of the pipe, and the second is the write of the pipe.

Pipes are by no means only used by the shell, though that is probably the most common place to use them.  However, you have it backwards; the shell can only use the system calls provided by the system, and because the system provides `pipe()`, the shell is able to provide piping.  Without the support from the o/s in the form of the system call, the shell would be unlikely to provide the pipe notation.  All the system calls are there to make it possible for programmers to provide services to their customers (the end users of the software they write).

Comment: Even without support for a pipe syscall or multitasking, one can implement pipe-like semantics. DOS command.com does it by redirecting the output of one command to a file first before starting the second command. (That of course has implications and certain restrictions..)

Answer (score 3):

They're the file descriptors returned by `pipe(2,3p)`. See the `pipe(2)` man page for more details.

Answer (score 1):

They are the file descriptors.  And piping isn't just used in the shell.  Piping can be done by any program and it's the primary way for processes to exchange information in Unix.  It is not something special to a shell.  A shell is just a normal process that makes it easy for the user to start other processes.